# blazor inputtextarea does not accept SQL query as input

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am building application, that should handle SQL queries.
In my Blazor server side application, I have a page with edit form. Here is how my form looks like

```
<EditForm Model="@FLOW" 
OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"
OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    
        
            <InputTextArea class="form-control" id="flowQuery" @bind-Value="@FLOW.Query"></InputTextArea>
            <label for="flowQuery">Direct query input</label>
            <ValidationMessage class="text-danger" For="@(()=>FLOW.Query)" />
        
        
    </EditForm>
```

This is how Model class looks like.

```
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title is too long.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    public string Query { get; set; }
```

I am using @bind-Value on InputTextArea input.
The problem is when I am trying to use actual SQL query, I suspect that Blazor detects possible SQL injection attack, and sets my @FLOW.Query string to null. As a result, form fires validation error, since the field is required.

I tried posting simple string, it worked fine. But it won't accept my huge SQL script.
My SQL script is 425 line 17271 characters long, with various declares, drops, groups, selets and inserts. (I am making a small tool for data-engeneers).

Is there a way to disable SQL injection detection for this field? Or maybe there is some kind of length check?

Comment: Are you using blazor server or blazor wasm?

Comment: As mentioned in 2nd sentence, it's blazor server application.

Comment: You said posting a string works what about a string as long as the script?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37973

Comment: Bingo, that issue link worked like a charm. And you where correct, my request did exceed MaximumReceiveMessageSize  I increased this value to allow 32MB instead of default 32KB and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Server side Blazor app is using SignalR, that by default has 32KB message size limit.
My request was twice that size. So I had to expand it.

Added this code to Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;    
    hubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 32768*1024; // 32 MB
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```

More details here: [github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37973](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37973)